# checked radio button from JSP scriptlet variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, radio-button, scriptlet

This is going to be a stupid question but i need to ask it.
PS: this is an old practice but i need it this way.
In scriptlet I have a variable `status`.

```
 <%
   String status=bean.getStatus();
   //Status value is coming from database which is either "1" or "0"(String type)
 %>
```

In a form I have radio button.

```
<tr>
<td> Status :</td>
<td>Active
            <input type="radio" name="status" checked="checked" id="statusAct" value="1" />
    Inactive
           <input type="radio" name="status" id="statusInac" value="0"/>
</tr>
```

If `status==1` I want radio button with `id="statusAct"` to be selected and if `status==0` then radio with `id="statusInac"` to be selected.

I can use javascript or Jquery but I don't know how to put Java variable inside javascript function.

Comment: Maybe `var status = "<% string......%>";` and then `if(status == '1') { $('#id').prop('checked', true); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
<input type="radio" name="status" <% ${bean.getStatus() == '1' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' } %> id="statusAct" value="1" />
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="status" <% ${bean.getStatus() == '0' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' } %> id="statusInac" value="1" />
```

Comment: Hello, I was trying to use it for input parameter from URL but getting error `Syntax error on token "$", AssignmentOperator expected after this token`
See my syntax: 
`<input  type="radio" name="options" value="tracking" autocomplete="off" <% ${param.options == 'tracking' ? 'checked="checked"' : '' } %> >`

Answer (score 0):

Either use scriptlets to do conditional logic and write checked ="checked" where you need to. In the scriptlets you can do out. println to write to the page (output stream). 
You could also use jstl for condition tags  c:if